# Cython optimize the critical part of a numpy array summation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, profiling, cython

Let L be a list `L = [A_1, A_2, ..., A_n]`, and each of the `A_i` are `numpy.int32` arrays of length 1024.

(Most of the time 1000 < n < 4000).

After some profiling, I have seen that one the most time consuming operation is the summation :

```
def summation():
    # L is a global variable, modified outside of this function
    b = numpy.zeros(1024, numpy.int32)
    for a in L:
        b += a
    return b
```

PS : I don't think I can define a 2D array of size `1024 x n` because `n` is not fixed : some elements are removed / added to L dynamically, so `len(L) = n` can vary between 1000 and 4000 during the running time.

**Can I get a significant improvement by using Cython ?
If so, how should I cython-recode this small function (shouldn't I add some `cdef` typing ?)**

Or can you see some possible other improvements ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Cython code, make sure that every array in L is C_CONTIGUOUS:

```
import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def sum_list(list a):
    cdef int* x
    cdef int* b
    cdef int i, j
    cdef int count
    count = len(a[0])
    res = np.zeros_like(a[0])
    b = <int *>((<np.ndarray>res).data)
    for j in range(len(a)):
        x = <int *>((<np.ndarray>a[j]).data)
        for i in range(count):
            b[i] += x[i]
    return res
```

One my PC it's about 4x faster.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It helped me a lot ! Do you know how I can modify this code if a[0], a[1], etc. are `int16 numpy arrays`, and I want the result `res` to be still a `int32 numpy array`  ?

Comment: If the input arrays are `int16`, and output is still `int32`, I replaced `cdef int* x` by `cdef short* x` and `x = <int *>((<np.ndarray>a[j]).data)`  by  `<short *>`.  Do you think it's the best way to do it ?